# Default Checkbox style in Android ICS is different from previous versions

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am checking my app in ICS and i notices that my checkboxes, that were gray in previous version, are currently black.
This is problematic because the background is also black.

How can i apply the style of previous versions (such as Honeycomb) to my checkboxes?

Comment: If you have custom background, then you should use custom checkbox button to avoid such cases.. Else have a transparent or default background

Comment: I want to use the default background of previous versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i apply the style of previous versions (such as Honeycomb) to my checkboxes?

This is not possible. You will need that background as resource in your project locally. You cannot access old versions android resources from system.